# How to force reloading php.ini file?

Tags: php, apache, configuration

I configured a web server last week, it worked fine.

Today I request its homepage, I see a timezone error, as it should be configured into my php.ini file.

I try a `phpinfo();` on my webserver, it gives me:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /opt/rrh/php/lib
```

But no php.ini file loaded.

I investigate, the php file exists and has very large permissions:

```
 ls -la /opt/rrh/php/lib   
 -rwxrwxrwx  1 apache root 68448 Nov 22 10:10 php.ini
```

I try a `parse_ini_file("/opt/rrh/php/lib/php.ini"));`, it returns no error...

Of course I restart my server a dozen of time.

What can I do more to resolve my problem?

My system:

1. Redhat 6
2. Apache 2.4
3. PHP 5.5.19 with `libphp5.so` apache module

Comment: that may be related: [restart php-fpm](http://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm/506951)

Comment: That ma bye helpful:
[restart php-fpm](http://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm/506951)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/21437/in-ubuntu-i-make-changes-to-php-ini-but-nothing-happens/21439#21439

Answer (score 39):

TL;DR; If you're still having trouble after restarting apache or nginx, also try restarting the `php-fpm` service.

The answers here don't always satisfy the requirement to force a reload of the php.ini file. On numerous occasions I've taken these steps to be rewarded with no update, only to find the solution I need after also **restarting the php-fpm service**. So if restarting apache or nginx doesn't trigger a php.ini update although you know the files are updated, try restarting php-fpm as well.

To restart the service:

Note: prepend sudo if not root

Using SysV Init scripts directly:

```
/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart        # typical
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart       # debian-style
/etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart     # debian-style PHP 7
```

Using service wrapper script

```
service php-fpm restart        # typical
service php5-fpm restart       # debian-style
service php7.0-fpm restart.    # debian-style PHP 7
```

Using Upstart (e.g. ubuntu):

```
restart php7.0-fpm         # typical (ubuntu is debian-based) PHP 7
restart php5-fpm           # typical (ubuntu is debian-based)
restart php-fpm            # uncommon
```

Using systemd (newer servers):

```
systemctl restart php-fpm.service        # typical
systemctl restart php5-fpm.service       # uncommon
systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service     # uncommon PHP 7
```

Or whatever the equivalent is on your system.

The above commands taken directly from [this server fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm)

Comment: For DigitalOcean Ubuntu users, `sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service` did the trick.

Comment: RHEL 7 + Remi repo as source for php 8.1: systemctl restart php81-php-fpm. You can find the name of your php-fpm by typing systemctl --type=service --state=running

Comment: Use the command to find out the service name `service --status-all | grep 'php'`

Answer (score 31):

To force a reload of the php.ini you should restart apache.

Try `sudo service apache2 restart` from the command line. 
Or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Answer (score 11):

You also can use graceful restart the apache server with `service apache2 reload` or `apachectl -k graceful`. 
As the apache [doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html) says:

> The USR1 or graceful signal causes the parent process to advise the
>   children to exit after their current request (or to exit immediately
>   if they're not serving anything). The parent re-reads its
>   configuration files and re-opens its log files. As each child dies off
>   the parent replaces it with a child from the new generation of the
>   configuration, which begins serving new requests immediately.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apachectl restart` does the job in 2021 running Mac latest Big Sur OS

For Homebrew apache users it's `brew services restart httpd`